# Sending mails using xampp and sendmail

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail.exe

i'm curerntly having a problem with sending mails from my local XAMPP server. i changed my sendmail.ini file with the following settings:

[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
debug_logfile=debug.log
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=myusername
auth_password=mypassword
force_sender=myusername
```

in my php.ini at the mail part i commented all lines except for this one:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

the error i get is the following:

```
Socket Error # 10060 Connection timed out.
```

the operating system i use is windows 8.1. On other computers who have the exact same xampp installation it works fine.

does anybody have an idea what could be the problem?